# Don't understand error of LaTeX after creating a new environment

Tags: errors, environments, minted

I'm using the `minted`-package to color code in a paper I'm writing. In order to change the style of the parts where my code will be displayed later down the road I defined a new enviroment. However, LaTeX somehow doesn't want to work with it.

Here's what I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{pythoncode}[0]{\begin{minted}{python}}{\end{minted}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pythoncode}
from foo import bar
\end{pythoncode}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. Latex throws an error:

> File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
>    
>                  \par 
>   <*> bib.tex
>
> I suspect you have forgotten a '}', causing me
>   to read past where you wanted me to stop.
>   I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
>   you'd better type 'E' or 'X' now and fix your file.
>
> ! Emergency stop.
>   <*> foo.tex
>
> *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pdf is produced after that. I tried highliting the code without `\newenvironment` (just using `\begin{minted}{python}` right inside the document), it works perfectly fine.

What am I doing wrong?? There is no `}` missing, is there?

I'm using pdflatex on [sharelatex.com](http://sharelatex.com/).

Comment: I think this is the `verbatim` content of `minted` -- it doesn't see `\end{minted}` correctly then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not the proper way to define an alias for `minted` environment.

You can use `newminted` like

```
\newminted{python}{linenos}
```

and then use `pythoncode` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{python}{linenos}

\begin{document}

\begin{pythoncode}
from foo import bar
\end{pythoncode}

%% above one is equivalent to the following
\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}
from foo import bar
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's great! Thanks! However, maybe you want point in your answer that the environment `pythoncode` is created automatically after the command `\newminted{python}{linenos}` is executed - I've had some trouble connecting that. But thanks! I works now.

Comment: @Nearoo Once you say `\newminted{python}{linenos}` the `pythoncode` environment becomes available. Similarly if you say `\newminted{cpp}{linenos}` `cppcode` becomes available and hence forth.